# MySQL TIMESTAMP BETWEEN 2 hours ago and 3 days ago

Tags: mysql, timestamp, between

Trying to do MySQL query on a `TIMESTAMP` Field.

I get close to getting the correct result but it always does just 3 days behind, nothing in the current day.  I believe it has something to do with utilizing `BETWEEN` with a `TIMESTAMP` field.

```
SELECT
    billing_first_name,
    cart_id,
    placed_ts,
    s_email           
FROM   `orders`
WHERE `paypal_response` IS NULL
   AND `authorize_response` IS NULL
   AND `s_email` IS NOT NULL
   AND (`placed_ts` BETWEEN
        DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
        AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 HOUR))     
GROUP BY `cart_id`
ORDER BY placed_ts DESC
```

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions like `COUNT()` or `SUM()`? The results will be from unpredictable rows in all the rows with the same `cart_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using `DATE(NOW())` instead of just `NOW()`. This discards the time of day, so it subtracts 2 hours from the beginning of the day (i.e. it returs 10pm on the previous day), rather than 2 hours before now.

```
AND (`placed_ts` BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR))
```

Comment: I think there's more wrong here than just that however

Comment: @Strawberry You mean like using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation?

Comment: @Barmar not sure how to answer the `GROUP BY` question, however I do get the desired results if I remove the `DATE()` portion.  The `cart_id` field is now unique but months ago was not therefore to clear things up I simply use a `GROUP BY`, however it is not necessarily needed whilst looking in the desired time frame, thank you.

Comment: If `cart_id` is unique then `GROUP BY cart_id` is unnecessary.